# What do you call the individual sections of a subway train?

Tags: single-word-requests

What's the common name? Wagon? Passenger car?

Example sentence:

> I sat two wagons from Tom to spy him.

Comment: I would call them "cars".

Comment: Most in the US would call them "cars" -- flat car, passenger car, coal car, tank (or tanker) car, box car.  I believe the Brits prefer "wagon".

Comment: @Hot Licks: The [Oxford Dictionary Online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/wagon) specifies "freight" in its definition of *wagon* as relating to railroads: "*British* A railway freight vehicle." On passenger trains in the U.K., they are called [carriages](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/carriage). In the U.S., we would call them *freight cars* and *passenger cars*.

Comment: And getting back to the question, since subway trains don't carry freight, we wouldn't call them *passenger cars*; we'd just call them *cars*. Or *subway cars* if you need to distinguish them from the kind that have internal combustion engines and travel on surface streets.

Comment: @HotLicks As A Brit, I'd never call a carriage a wagon.

Comment: What @Matthew said. I think *wagons* went out with *wains* in the old country. Anyway, we certainly never had *wagon **trains***.

Comment: It's called a _bogie_ in Indian English.

Comment: I gather US Americans use either *freight* or *passenger cars*.

We Brits use *wagons* or *trucks* for *freight* and *carriages* or sometimes, *coaches* for passengers.

I can't disagree with  Himabindu and in British English a *bogie* is a set of wheels and their suspension, on which the carriages, cars, coaches, trucks or wagons sit.

I don't know enough about railways to say whether modern *engines* have bogies and I think traditionally steam engines didn't, because their suspension was different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general usage in the US would be [***cars***](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/car) (if the context is clear) or ***subway cars*** (if the context requires clarification). I don't have a reference, but I believe that the British/Commonwealth usage is generally ***carriage*** or ***wagon***.

Comment: Source: [The Taking of Pelham 123](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Taking_of_Pelham_One_Two_Three_(1974_film)): "On the New York City Subway, four men armed with submachine guns, wearing similar disguises, and using code names (Mr. Blue, Mr. Green, Mr. Grey, and Mr. Brown) board a downtown (southbound) 6 train at different station stops. The men take 17 passengers (one an undercover police officer) and the conductor hostage in the train's first car, and leave the rest of the train behind ." Don't have a Brit reference. If you like this source, feel free to use it.

Comment: @ab2 - The link on ***cars*** in the answer provides the reference for the US usage (see definition 2); it's for the UK/Commonwealth usage that I didn't have a reference, other than technically anecdotal (knowing people who are from UK and other Commonwealth countries). It's slightly smileworthy (to me) that you quote WP on ToP123; I'm from NYC.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that cars was a link.  I can't imagine anyone writing a thriller about DC's Metro.

Comment: In India we can it a 'coach'. Google 'train coaches'. But of course this has British origins.